# Does the Azure ServiceBus JMS library support managed identities?

Tags: spring, azure, jms, azure-managed-identity

I am using the library `com.azure.spring:azure-spring-boot-starter-servicebus-jms:3.14.0` and I am trying to avoid the usage of a connection string by using a managed identity, but I wasn't able to find anything related on the internet. I also examined the library and I haven't seen any support for `TokenCredential` what Microsoft usually supports.

So the question is whether it is currently supported by the library or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

The JMS API itself has no support for a "managed identity" or any kind of `TokenCredetial` object.

The JMS client *implementation* used here is [Qpid JMS](https://qpid.apache.org/components/jms/index.html) and it also has no support for a "managed identity" or any kind of `TokenCredetial` object.